# socket.io without using default namespace/room feature

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I found it's easier to just setup own custom path for multiple endpoints like this

server side:

```
io.on('connection', function(client) {

  var username = client.handshake.headers.users[0].username;

  client.on(username+'_con1', function(data) {
      io.emit(username+'_con1',data);
  });

  client.on(username+'_con2', function(data) {
      io.emit(username+'_con2',data);
  });

}
```

Is above approach correct? at least I'm able to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean by correct. This will create multiple events for the client.

Its hard to say if this is the best/correct way without any context. But you should look into namespaces and rooms and decide for yourself! http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

Answer (score 1):

Creating unique message names for each client makes it seem like you plan on sending a message to all clients and only some clients will be listening for the message directed at them.  This is not a very efficient way to do things.

Rooms in socket.io are designed such that you can have a common message name (no need for a unique message name for each client) and then send that message only to the clients that it is intended for.  That's a lot more efficient scheme.

Now, of course, you could create the unique message name for each client and then only send it to the desired client, but why bother with the extra complication of the unique message name.  You don't need it if you're only sending the message to the intended client.

So, you could certainly make your scheme work, but it does not seem like it's the simplest way to do things and, depending upon other details of your implementation, it may not be the most efficient way to do things either.

A namespace is more like connecting to a particular channel.  The client decides what channel they want to connect to.  The server then decides which namespace to send a given message to.

A room is a something a server subscribes a client to in order to make it easy to send a specific set of clients the same messages or in some cases to share incoming messages from one client with all the other clients in a room (like in chat).

Comment: so i have a web app that has 3 module (says it's dashboard,setting,catalog) I need to have just 1 connection and use 3 namespace instead of 3 unique endpoints?